# How can i make it so that when mouse button 4 is pressed it will stop the script from working, basically a kill-switch

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I am Wondering how to make it so when mouse button 4 is pressed it stops or adds a very long rest. basically a kill switch that disables the auto clicker from working

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   --OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then 
      repeat 
         PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(math.random(40, 135)) 
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
   end
end
```

Comment: The script stops working when you release mouse button 5.  Is it not enough?

Answer (score 0):

`until` in Lua defines exit condition of the repeat-until loop.
Try to replace

```
until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
```

with

```
until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) or IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
```

Comment: I was talking about a killswitch for the script that when pressed it will make the script not work at all, I recently figured out that simply crashing the code or force causing an error will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   --OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then 
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true) 
elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then 
 ReleaseMouseButton(1)
 ReleaseMouseButton(2) --prevent stuck
end 
if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7) then 
        enable = not 
        enable point = not point 
end    
if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5) and enable then 
      repeat 
         PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(math.random(40, 135)) 
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
   end
end
```

MBTN 7 ll be ur switch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).